# Как запустить чат?

Tags: java, vaadin, jms

Только начинаю вникать в jms и vaadin так что не судите строго за нубский вопрос. Есть простой пример jms чат https://github.com/mstahv/java-ee-jms-vaadin-chat

Сервер wildfly запускается, на localhost://8080 открывается приветственная страница сервера. А на каком url само приложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите по пути: http://localhost:8080/java-ee-jms-chat, обычно если в WEB.xml не указывается, обращение идет через название war файла.

Comment: Работает на http://localhost:8080/java-ee-jms-chat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/